# PHP pass file into the recursiveArrayIterator

Tags: php, json

Is there a way to pass in a file path to the RecursiveArrayIterator something like

```
 //new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode("array from file ", TRUE)),
```

I know I can read from files with:

```
           $fileSPLObjects  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
           new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
           RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
```

Which will allow me to read in the JSON array from a file instead of defining it on the page.
So basically is there a way to combine these two code snippets?

```
 $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
 new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
 RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get bonus points for collapsing as many lines of code into a single line as possible.  Why not just use something like this?

```
$json = file_get_contents($json_file_path);
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
if (is_null($json_array)) {
    // json decode failed. Error handling here
} else {
   $iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($json_array);
}
```

Comment: that's the first thing I tried, but I got `Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead'

Comment: @Edward Do you have valid JSON? I have updated my answer to actually show a more proper way to achieve this (by verifying decode step works before trying to operate on array).

Comment: It's strange because when I copy/paste the file contents into a Json checker I get the JSON is valid, but when I print_r the read file and post that into the checker I get The JSON Data field does not contain JSON data. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @Edward Check your error logs or `error_get_last()`. You could have line breaks or something else screwing things up. Make sure you are working with a compacted (i.e. not prettified) JSON string.  If you tried to copy/paste a pretty printed JSON string into a file and then read that file, you have likely introduced line breaks.